# XCode C/C++ Flags Bash Script

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Im trying to run the following command on XCode adding it as a C/C++ Flags to I can get the build number coming from a shell script that is executed at the run script phase of my project.

This work fine with GCC on another Unix like system:

-D__BUILD_VERSION=$(cat build_number)

And ok XCode Im trying to use the following:

-D__BUILD_VERSION=$(cat $PROJECT_DIR/build_number)

But it doesn't work, what Im I doing wrong? In XCode, how can I assign the result of cat build_number to the __BUILD_VERSION defined variable?

Comment: I ran into this as well and created a new q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524925/compilation-flags-using-bash-in-xcode/31541953#31541953
I know it's been a couple years and might not apply to you at this point, but I also did manage to get it to work (see my answer on the same page)

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to set that value in the Xcode compile build-phase, you may run into trouble, as i don't know that any interpretive operation takes place with the settings you are trying to set up the way you are trying to set them up.

for auto-setting the version number, i have a much more complex semi-auto-version and auto-numbering scheme so i don't have to remember to change either, or so i can give a version-number i want but always increment the build number, and in both cases, it will put the build number in the About box in the app-settings that are displayed in the iOS system settings.

you may not need much of any of it, but there are a couple of tricks for getting and writing information that you may find useful and may lead to a solution for your problem.

---

the following scripts were inspired by a stack-overflow answer for how to do this that i can't find at the moment.  i put in a bit more work, because (a) i want the version number to show up in the settings displayed in system settings; and (b) Xcode caches the contents of the Info.plist file, so doing this is not nearly as simple as i would have expected.

in a build phase that comes before compile, i run the following (with **Run script only when installing** *unchecked*)

```
sh xolawareStashProductSettings.sh
```

the contents of xolawareStashProductSettings.sh check the git status of the info.plist file, and if not clean, stash it aside temporarily for later restoration.

```
#!/bin/sh

#
# should be run prior to the Copy Bundle Resources step
# and prior to any version information modifier scripts

INFOPLIST_GIT_PATH=${PROJECT}/`basename ${INFOPLIST_FILE}`
echo "-- Temp Hold ${INFOPLIST_GIT_PATH} Script --"

set -e

# a fallback in case the user has made changes to the file
if [ `git status --porcelain ${INFOPLIST_GIT_PATH} ]|wc -l` -gt 0 ]; then
    echo cp -p ${INFOPLIST_GIT_PATH} ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}
    cp -p ${INFOPLIST_GIT_PATH} ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}
fi
```

script #2 (with **Run script only when installing** *unchecked*):

```
sh xolawareStashSettingsBundleRootPlist.sh
```

the contents of xolawareStashSettingsBundleRootPlist.sh are similar to the contents of script 1.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# should be run prior to the Copy Bundle Resources step
# and prior to any version information modifier scripts

echo '-- Temp Hold Settings.bundle/Root.plist Script --'

ROOT_PLIST=${PROJECT}/Resources/Settings.bundle/Root.plist

set -e

# a fallback in case the user has made changes to the file
if [ `git status --porcelain ${ROOT_PLIST} ]|wc -l` -gt 0 ]; then
    echo cp -p ${ROOT_PLIST} ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}
    cp -p ${ROOT_PLIST} ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}
fi
```

script #3 (with **Run script only when installing** *checked*)

```
sh xolawareIncrementProductSettingsBuildNumber.sh
```

the contents of xolawareIncrementProductSettingsBuildNumber use plistbuddy to see what it is and bump it by one:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# this should be prior to xolawareAboutInfoVersionInfoInSettings.sh

echo "-- Auto-Increment ${INFOPLIST_FILE} Build Version Install Script --"

PLISTBUDDYCMD="/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c"
CONFIGURATION_BUILD_SETTINGS_PATH=${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}

CFBV=$(${PLISTBUDDYCMD} "Print :CFBundleVersion" ${PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH})
if [[ "${CFBV}" == "" ]]; then
    echo "No build number in ${PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH}"
    exit 2
fi

CFBV=$(expr $CFBV + 1)

set -e
echo ${PLISTBUDDYCMD} "Set :CFBundleVersion $CFBV" "${PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH}"
${PLISTBUDDYCMD} "Set :CFBundleVersion $CFBV" "${PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH}"
echo ${PLISTBUDDYCMD} "Set :CFBundleVersion $CFBV" "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_SETTINGS_PATH}"
${PLISTBUDDYCMD} "Set :CFBundleVersion $CFBV" "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_SETTINGS_PATH}"
```

script #4  (with **Run script only when installing** *unchecked*)

```
sh xolawareProductSettingsShortVersion-from-git.sh
sh xolawareAboutInfoVersionInfoInSettings.sh
```

the contents of xolawareProductSettingsShortVersion-from-git rely a little on me tagging my branch in git appropriately, but if i forget, it will use the number of commits since the last commit to auto-version my build for me.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# this should be run after xolawareStashSettingsBundleRootPlist.sh
# and prior to xolawareAboutInfoVersionInfoInSettings.sh

echo '-- Get Product Settings Short Version String from git describe --'

PLISTBUDDYCMD="/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c"
CONFIGURATION_BUILD_SETTINGS_PATH=${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}

CFBVS=`git describe|awk '{split($0,a,"-"); print a[1]}'`
CFBVSI=`git describe|awk '{split($0,a,"-"); print a[2]}'`
if [[ "$CFBVSI" != "" ]]; then
    CFBVS=${CFBVS}.${CFBVSI}
fi

set -e
echo ${PLISTBUDDYCMD} "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $CFBVS" "${PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH}"
${PLISTBUDDYCMD} "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $CFBVS" "${PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH}"
echo ${PLISTBUDDYCMD} "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $CFBVS" "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_SETTINGS_PATH}"
${PLISTBUDDYCMD} "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $CFBVS" "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_SETTINGS_PATH}"
```

the contents of xolawareAboutInfoVersionInfoInSettings.sh place the contents in the About box in my Root.plist like i want.  it relies on the About box being the first thing in your Root.plist of your settings.bundle:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# this should be invoked after xolawareStashInfoAndRootPlist.sh,
# xolawareIncrementProductSettingsBuildNumber.sh and 
# xolawareProductSettingsShortVersion-from-git.sh, and before
# the regular Copy Bundle Resources Build Phase

echo '-- Auto-Insert Version Info In System Settings Script --'

PLISTBUDDYCMD="/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c"
ROOT_PLIST=${PROJECT_DIR}/${PROJECT}/Resources/Settings.bundle/Root.plist

CFBSVS=`exec -c ${PLISTBUDDYCMD} "Print :CFBundleShortVersionString" ${PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH}`
CFBV=`exec -c ${PLISTBUDDYCMD} "Print :CFBundleVersion" ${PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH}`

set -e
echo ${PLISTBUDDYCMD} "Set :PreferenceSpecifiers:1:DefaultValue '${CFBSVS} (b${CFBV})'" ${ROOT_PLIST}
${PLISTBUDDYCMD} "Set :PreferenceSpecifiers:1:DefaultValue '${CFBSVS} (b${CFBV})'" ${ROOT_PLIST}
```

there are also a couple of cleanup scripts to be run after the Compile, Link & Copy bundle resources phases

```
sh xolawareStashRestoreSettingsBundleRootPlist.sh
```

this may not be necessary, but i adjust other items in the Root.plist for release builds, so this restores those settings for debug builds.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# should be run as the second to last script in Build Phases, after the Copy Bundle Resources Phase

echo "-- Manual Restore $INFOPLIST_FILE Script --"

ROOT_PLIST=${PROJECT}/Resources/Settings.bundle/Root.plist

set -e

# first, see if it was stashed earlier due to uncommitted changes
if [ -e ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}/Root.plist ]; then
    echo mv ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}/Root.plist ${ROOT_PLIST}
    mv ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}/Root.plist ${ROOT_PLIST}

# the better option when available: restore to the pristine state
elif [ `git status --porcelain ${ROOT_PLIST}|wc -l` -gt 0 ]; then
    echo git checkout -- ${ROOT_PLIST}
    git checkout -- ${ROOT_PLIST}
fi
```

and finally, the step to auto-tag the git repo if i haven't already tagged the item just now myself:

```
sh xolawareProductSettings-git-commit-and-tag.sh


#!/bin/sh
#
# this should be run after xolawareAboutInfoVersionInfoInSettings.sh
# and xolawareProductSettingsShortVersion-from-git.sh

echo "-- ${INFOPLIST_FILE} git commit & tag Install Script --"

SCRIPT_VERSION=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print :CFBundleShortVersionString' ${INFOPLIST_FILE}`
SCRIPT_BUILD_NUMBER=`/usr/libexec/Plistbuddy -c 'Print :CFBundleVersion' ${INFOPLIST_FILE}`
if [ `git status --porcelain ${SCRIPT_INFO_PLIST}|wc -l` -gt 0 ]; then
    echo git commit -m '"'version ${SCRIPT_VERSION} build ${SCRIPT_BUILD_NUMBER}'"' ${INFOPLIST_FILE}
    git commit -m "version ${SCRIPT_VERSION} build ${SCRIPT_BUILD_NUMBER}" ${INFOPLIST_FILE}
fi
echo git tag -f ${SCRIPT_VERSION}
git tag -f -F /dev/null ${SCRIPT_VERSION}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
-D__BUILD_VERSION=`cat $PROJECT_DIR/build_number`
```

Note the "backticks" - they're not regular single quote characters.

Comment: Backticks it is... thanks a bunch I knew the answer was simple ;)

Comment: Oups... that wasn't it not XCode generate the following as command line:"-D__BUILD_VERSION=`cat" "<mypath>build_number`"

Answer (score 0):

One possibility might be to have the first script put the build number into an environment variable?  Not sure if that would work but it might.